# python3: Run C file and python script in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-3.5

Ive got a snipped of my actual python script written in this post. Basically I want to have a C programm and a Pyserial function executed in parallel (the C programm is for controlling a motor, the pySerial is for communicating with a arduino). My programm will be executed on a RPi3b using Spyder3 and Rasbipian.
What Ive already figured out from the sources below is that if you want to have a terminal program executed in python you should use the subprocess class. If you want to execute something in parallel the Process package from multiprocessing will do the job.
So Ive mixed them together and tried to archive my goals by using the code bleow. Unluckly without any success. The p1 process immediatly starts after the p1 process is called [ p1 = Process(target=run_c_file()) ] and the script stops until the C file has finished. Does anyone out there can help? Thank you very much!

BTW Im using python 3.5...

My sources:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html , https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess

```
import serial_comm as ssf #My own function. Tested and working when single calling

import subprocess as sub
from multiprocessing import Process

def run_c_file():
  sub.run("./C_File") #Call the C File in the same directory. Immeidatly starts when script is at line 14 -> p1 = Process(target=run_c_file())


def run_pyserial(ser_obj):
  ssf.command(ser_obj,"Command") #Tell the arduino to do something fancy (tested and working)

ser_obj = ssf.connect()
p1 = Process(target=run_c_file())
p2 = Process(target=run_pyserial(ser_obj))

try:
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join() #Process one should start here (as far as I understood)
    p2.join() #Process two should start here (as far as I understood)
'''The following part is still in progress'''
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Aborting")

p1.terminate()
p2.terminate()
```

Comment: If you want your Python program to launch an external program, then the language in which the external program was implemented has very little to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
p1 = Process(target=run_c_file)
p2 = Process(target=run_pyserial, args=(ser_obj,))
```

currently you are calling the function instead of passing it.

Comment: Whoop! Woks! Thanks a lot!